# Switching views/controllers in an outlet causes an attribute binding to break

Tags: ember.js

We are building an app where a part of it concerns choosing an element from a list;
we use an outlet for this and switch between two views: one displaying the currently chosen element `('detailView')`, and one displaying a list of all elements to choose from `('listView')` - it works rather like a drop-down list. The list element that represent the currently chosen element in the list view also has a class, `is-selected`, that is a bound attribute.

When we switch from the list view to the detail view (as a result of a click by the user, meaning that he has chosen an element) we update an object denoting the currently selected item. This causes the class attribute binding on our list elements in the list view to produce an error in the Ember library (in the `EmberHandlebars.bindClasses` function).

It looks like the function mentioned is trying to update the attribute binding with regards to the new value, and does so by finding the corresponding HTML-code. The problem is that this HTML does not exist at the moment, because we have switched views.

I made a Fiddle with an example of what we are trying to do: *http://jsfiddle.net/7k8n7/2/*

Please, if you find any design choices in this example that you think is bad, don't hesitate to mention it; however the point of the Fiddle is simply to create the error in a piece of code that we think should work.

The code that produces the error is:

```
goToDetail : function(router, event) {
    router.transitionTo('detail');
    router.get('selectedModel').set('content', event.context);
}
```

If one switches the order of the two lines in this function, then the `detail-view` won't even be displayed.

Comment: I think the error is related to this bug: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1236, which is corrected on  master (and ember-latest).

Comment: @sly7_7: Thanks, you are completely right; this issue is the same as ours and it's fixed in ember-latest.